# How to save the LDAP SSL Certificate from OpenSSL

Tags: ssl, ldap, openssl, ssl-certificate, edirectory

I wanted the SSL Certificate of my LDAP Server which is Novell eDirectory. I have used openssl to connect to ldap to view the certificate.

```
openssl s_client -connect 192.168.1.225:636
```

It is just printing the certificate. How can I save this to some certificate format file?

Answer (score 117, accepted):

Copy everything between `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----` and `-----END CERTIFICATE-----` (including these delimiters) and paste it in a new text file (usually with the extension `.pem` or `.crt`). You can use your favourite (plain) text editor for this, for example Notepad, Gedit, Vim, Emacs (depending on the system you're using).

Alternatively, you can pipe the output to `sed -ne '/-BEGIN CERTIFICATE-/,/-END CERTIFICATE-/p'`, as described [here](http://www.madboa.com/geek/openssl/#cert-retrieve):

```
echo -n | openssl s_client -connect 192.168.1.225:636 | sed -ne '/-BEGIN CERTIFICATE-/,/-END CERTIFICATE-/p' > ldapserver.pem
```

Comment: A tangential concern: how to retrieve the SSL certificate returned by StartTLS (when LDAPS is disabled). A: as of `OpenSSL 0.9.8r 8 Feb 2011` this is not possible. OpenSSL does not yet support the LDAP protocol for StartTLS.

Answer (score 14):

For those looking to grab the certs over a LDAP connection using StartTLS:

I have [re-submitted a patch](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/pull/1735) to OpenSSL to support LDAP when using -starttls for s_client. So eventually this should work <s>(if it ever makes it in I guess -- not yet as of 10/18/16)</s>:

`openssl s_client -connect servername:389 -starttls ldap -showcerts`

**Edit**: Support was eventually merged under [this PR](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/pull/2293). C is not my forte so luckily someone else ran with it ;)

I also wrote a PHP function to extract the SSL certificates after issuing a STARTTLS command over a TCP connection. It could easily be ported to other languages with a little work:

```
/**
 * @param string $server The server name to connect to
 * @param int $port The standard LDAP port
 * @return array In the form of ['peer_certificate' => '', 'peer_certificate_chain' => [] ]
 */
function getLdapSslCertificates($server, $port = 389)
{
    $certificates = [
        'peer_certificate' => null,
        'peer_certificate_chain' => [],
    ];
    // This is the hex encoded extendedRequest for the STARTTLS operation...
    $startTls = hex2bin("301d02010177188016312e332e362e312e342e312e313436362e3230303337");
    $opts = [
        'ssl' => [
            'capture_peer_cert' => true,
            'capture_peer_cert_chain' => true,
            'allow_self_signed' => true,
            'verify_peer' => false,
            'verify_peer_name' => false,
        ],
    ];

    $context = stream_context_create($opts);
    $client = @stream_socket_client(
        "tcp://$server:$port",
        $errorNumber,
        $errorMessage,
        5,
        STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT,
        $context
    );
    @stream_set_timeout($client, 2);
    @fwrite($client, $startTls);
    @fread($client, 10240);
    @stream_socket_enable_crypto($client, true, STREAM_CRYPTO_METHOD_TLS_CLIENT);
    $info = @stream_context_get_params($client);

    if (!$info) {
        return $certificates;
    }
    openssl_x509_export($info['options']['ssl']['peer_certificate'], $certificates['peer_certificate']);

    foreach ($info['options']['ssl']['peer_certificate_chain'] as $index => $cert) {
        $certChain = '';
        openssl_x509_export($cert, $certChain);
        $certificates['peer_certificate_chain'][$index] = $certChain;
    }
    @fclose($client);

    return $certificates;
}
```

The above function will return an array containing the peer certificate and the peer certificate chain. So it could be used like so:

```
// Just pass it the server name
$certificates = getLdapSslCertificates('dc1.example.local');

// The certificates are in the array as strings in PEM format
echo $certificates['peer_certificate'].PHP_EOL;
foreach ($certificates['peer_certificate_chain'] as $cert) {
    echo $cert.PHP_EOL;
}
```

Answer (score 9):

There is a pretty simple way using only `openssl`:

```
openssl s_client -connect 192.168.1.225:636 < /dev/null |
  openssl x509 -out cert.pem
```

The first line fetches the cert from server and the second line parses the cert and allows transforming it into different formats, for example:

- `openssl x509 -noout -text`: prints certificate in text format, e.g., for debugging.
- `openssl x509 -outform der -out cert.crt`: saves cert in DER format

You can checkout [docs](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man1/x509.html) for all possible variations.

Comment: Extra-ordinary explanation!

Answer (score 6):

The easiest way i found to save a certificate from any SSL enabled protocols like ldap, imap, pop, ftps, https etc. is just using chrome browser. Assume if your server running any protocol (like mentioned) create the url like this

http://: (example if your ldap server is running on SSL port 10636 it would be https://example.com:10636). Simply just hit this URL and obtain the certificate from the chrome browser itself. A simple demo below. In this demo my ldap server is using a self-signed certificate.

[image: Click On Certificate Information]

Click on copy to file and save the certificate by clicking next.

[image]

This method works for any server running on SSL irrespective of protocol.

Cheers.

Comment: Also works in Firefox almost the same.  In IE You need to save the cert to the Windows keystore first, then you can export it from there as a file.

Comment: I used to follow this, but if there is a check, LDAP admin can block saying unsafe port for HTTPS

Answer (score 5):

There is a tool that lets you collect and save an SSL/TLS certificate from a server that speaks not only LDAPS, but LDAP/STARTTLS too. That's a revision of the well-known [InstallCert](https://java.net/projects/javamail/pages/InstallCert) program, written in Java.

Just run it like this:

```
java -jar installcert-usn-20131123.jar host_name:port
```

and it will save the certificate for you in the `jssecacerts` keystore file in your JRE file tree, and also in the `extracerts` keystore file in your current directory. You can then use Java [keytool](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/keytool.html) to export the certificate(s) to other formats.

You are welcome to visit my blog page [Yet another InstallCert for Java, now with STARTTLS support](http://s-n-ushakov.blogspot.com/2013/11/yet-another-installcert-for-java-now.html) for download and instructions.

Comment: found another fork, for reference https://github.com/escline/InstallCert

Comment: i actually forked it and merged some of the other suggestions from SO and published to to central. code is here https://github.com/spyhunter99/installcert

Answer (score 3):

We liked using ldapsearch for performing this. The [whole process](https://ldapwiki.com/wiki/Obtain%20a%20Certificate%20from%20Server#section-Obtain+a+Certificate+from+Server-UsingLdapsearch), a few lines, but this is the gist of it:

```
ldapsearch -x -T ~/ -t -h your-edirectory-host.yourdomain.com -b "cn=Security" objectclass=nDSPKICertificateAuthority cACertificate
```

-jim

Comment: Assuming the certificate is in the directory.

Comment: He said "my LDAP Server which is Novell eDirectory" so it is in the directory.

Answer (score 1):

Or you can easily export the public and private key via iManager if you need them in either DER or PEM format. (DER is a binary format, PEM is a base64 encoded format, so in iManager, your choices will be DER or B64 and B64 ~= PEM in this context)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use https://keystore-explorer.org/ to export the certificate. Use Examine -> Examine SSL.