# Query on jvm truststore and jssecacerts file?

Tags: java, ssl, https

i have two https web applications app1 and app2 installed on two different tomcats t1 and t2(t1 and t2 are on different machines). when in app1 
i make an url connection to app2 i get the SSL handshake error. The reason is i am using the self signed certificate in app2 which is not present
in app1 jvm truststore. So proper approach to fix it  install the self signed certificate in      JAVA-HOME/jre/lib/security . To do the
same , I have followed the steps given at http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-ws/suncertpathbuilderexception-unable-to-find-valid-certification-path-to-requested-target/.
Same steps are suggested across the different forums. But still i get the same SSL handshake error which is

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path   building failed: sun.security.
provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to   requested target
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Unknown Source)
```

Though it i got rid of this SSLHandshakeException by mentioning below parameters in JVM trustore.
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=C:.keystore
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=changeit

**My question here is why first approach(which is proper approach) i.e putting the jssecacerts file under /lib/security is not working?** 
Another point is what is different between first and second approach ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Though it i got rid of this SSLHandshakeException by mentioning below
>   parameters in JVM trustore. -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=C:.keystore
>   -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=changeit

It's not clear what you were trying to do with these options. Either you use the default truststore (normally [`jssecacerts`, if it exists; otherwise, `cacerts`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/JSSERefGuide.html#Customization)) or you specify your own. `.keystore` tends to be used as a keystore, not truststore (although there is no default JSSE value). (I would also specify the full path instead of `C:.keystore`, by the way.)

It's probably better to make a copy of your original `cacerts` (or `jssecacerts`) file (remove the extra one you've put, if you've changed something) and add your remote certificate to it (i.e. app2's cert in app1's copy and app1's cert in app2's copy, if needed).

You can list the certificates using `keytool -list -keystore keystore.jks` (see help for more options if needed).

You can export a certificate using `keytool -export -keystore server1-keystore.jks -alias server_alias -file server1.crt`.

Then, import it in the other truststore: `keytool -import -keystore client2-truststore.jks -file server1.crt`. (Here, `client2-truststore.jks` will be a copy of `cacerts`.)
Then, configure your JVM running Apache Tomcat (not necessarily the Tomcat connector) to use it. You should be able to set the JVM parameters in `catalina.sh` (`JAVA_OPTS=-D...`).

**EDIT:**

> My question here is why first approach(which is proper approach) i.e
>   putting the jssecacerts file under /lib/security is not working?

To answer your question more directly, I've just double-checked on a clean Oracle JRE 6 installation (1.6.0_31), and `jssecacerts` takes precedence over `cacerts` when present (as documented in the JSSE Ref Guide, so there doesn't seem to be a bug). I'm not sure where Oracle have moved Andreas Sterbenz's Sun blog, so I'm not sure which copy of `InstallCert` you've used. I guess something my have gone wrong there.

As far as I'm aware, `InstallCert` connects to the server to get its certificate (replacing the export step above): you effectively assume that the certificate you get on your first connection is the right one (and can be trusted). You could also get that certificate [using OpenSSL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7086830/372643). However, in your case, you seem to have control over the two servers and their respective keystores, so you might as well use `keytool -export` to be sure.

> Another point is what is different between first and second approach ?

The first approach (changing `jssecacerts`) sets the configuration for all applications that will use this installation of the JRE, whereas the second will apply those settings to the JVM once it's running Apache Tomcat only.

Note, that if you didn't have a `jssecacerts` but only a `cacerts` file, if you only import your certificate into `jssecacerts`, `cacerts` will be ignored, so you won't be able to connect to servers that have a certificate issued by a CA that would normally be trusted by default. That's why starting with a copy of the default file can be useful. (In addition, if your application also connects to other sites that would normally be trusted by default, this could also explain why you'd get this error message, at a different place this time.)

Ultimately, [it's your responsiblity to check what's in `jssecacerts` or `cacerts`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/JSSERefGuide.html#CustomizingStores):

> IMPORTANT NOTE: The JDK ships with a limited number of trusted root
>   certificates in the /lib/security/cacerts file. As documented in
>   keytool, it is your responsibility to maintain (that is, add/remove)
>   the certificates contained in this file if you use this file as a
>   truststore.
>
> Depending on the certificate configuration of the servers you contact,
>   you may need to add additional root certificate(s). Obtain the needed
>   specific root certificate(s) from the appropriate vendor.

Comment: @ Bruno Thanks for your informative reply. At last it worked(after restart of my local box). I used the InstallCert.java at 
http://code.google.com/p/java-use-examples/source/browse/trunk/src/com/aw/ad/util/InstallCert.java. I have on more question.
This program generated the jssecacerts which will get precedence over cacerts. So is there a way instead of generating new
truststore i.e jssecacerts i can add my  self signed certificate in the existing  cacerts file (so that old cerfitificates
by verified CA's in existing cacerts file does not get ingnored).

Comment: For your information:-I have cacerts file by default inside jre\lib\security directory
not jssecacerts file

Comment: @MSach. Looking at the `InstallCert` code, it will generate a `jssecacerts` file, but load from `jssecacerts` or `cacerts`, so it makes a copy anyway. Not sure why you had to restart your box. Had you not restarted Tomcat after making those changes?

Comment: As you said Looking at the InstallCert code, it will generate a jssecacerts file, but load from jssecacerts or cacerts, so it makes a copy anyway. I think what you are trying to say here is, InstallCert code is making copy of all certificates present in cacerts file to new jssecacets file. So previous certificates present in cacerts file will not be ignored. Right?

Comment: Indeed, they should be copied too.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is that you added the certificate to the incorrect truststore file :). JRE's system truststore file is not jssecacerts but simply cacerts under ${JRE_HOME}/lib/security/. You were creating a new trustore which the JRE isn't aware of. Adding the certificate to the proper store will resolve your problem. However, let me warn you that it is not a good idea to add your custom CA certificates to the system truststore. Add them to the user truststore and use it the way you are using in the second option.

Comment: If we go thru Nic Brough post at http://forums.atlassian.com/thread.jspa?threadID=52713, looks like  jssecacerts is the first one  in search order for the locating the trust store . But if  go by your words that JRE is only aware of jssecacerts  not of jssecacerts .Then  if i run the program InstallCert given at http://code.google.com/p/java-use-examples/source/browse/trunk/src/com/aw/ad/util/InstallCert.java and mention the file name as cacert instead of jssecacerts won't it override the default root certificate already present in cacert ?

Comment: I am not aware of the search paths JRE goes through to find the stores. Nic might be correct but since you already tried doing it and it didnt work, I would be forced to believe that it doesnt work that way. The Truststore is simply a collection of trusted certificates of authorities in a specific order. Adding a new self signed certificate to the collection will not harm it. It is just a simple addition.

Comment: But again dont add your certificates to the system truststore because it would affect all JVM instances using that JRE. Using your own custom store is a good idea.

Comment: when you say add to user truststore you mean adding these parameters i.e -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=C:.keystore -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=changeit in jvm options of tomcat. Right?

Comment: This answer is completely incorrect. See the JSSE Reference Guide. Java will use jssecacerts if found, otherwise cacerts. If you don't know these details you shouldn't be posting about it.

Comment: Yes. I think you should go with @Bruno 's comment. He has put things elaborately and nicely.