# How can i use wget in order to obtain the public key?

Tags: c, ssl, openssl, wget, public-key

Is there any way to use *wget* directly or tweak the source code or use it with openssl in order to obtain the public key from a certificate and save it to a file?

Comment: If you just want to use the tool, it's probably more for SuperUser. Do you want to do it programmatically?

Comment: Yes indeed..The concept is that i have a list of hosts(around 1 million) and i want to get the public key of this hosts and store it to a file

Answer (score 1):

Not with wget, but with OpenSSL, you can use the same method as [in this question for LDAP](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7086830/372643) (except on port 443, if you're interested in HTTPS, presumably).

You can also pipe the output into the `openssl x509 -pubkey` to get the public key itself.

Something like this should do:

```
echo -n | openssl s_client -connect www.google.com:443 | sed -ne '/-BEGIN CERTIFICATE-/,/-END CERTIFICATE-/p' | openssl x509 -pubkey -noout
```